# ¿Cómo buscar dentro de un objecto en JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy creando una función en Vue para buscar dentro de un objeto y en la función paso unos parámetros (key) por ejemplo ('cesta.modal.title');

He estado haciendo pruebas y he visto que puedes buscar dentro de un objeto con `objeto.cesta.modal.title` y me gustaría replicar esto desde la función y no sé como hacer, ¿alguna idea que se os ocurra?

También he probado de poner el `objeto.key` y no funciona.

Comment: Comparte tu código para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte con tu consulta.

Comment: No te podemos ayudar si no muestras código. Danos más información.